# Select image from grid view and show it in next activity and in this activity there are buttons to capture image and also to save it

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, gridview

I am showing images from my gridview.
When an image is selected it is shown in new activity.
In new activity there is 2 buttons one to capture image and one to save it along with the image chosen from gridview.
My problem is that when I select image from gridview then the buttons in the next activity do not respond.And when they respond then chosen image from gridview is not shown.
Capture image and save buttons logic is in different class.
I am trying to call these by intent.

this is my code where the problem is,when i am using two intent then also only is working.

```
          public class SingleItemView extends Activity {
           //final static int CAMERA_RESULT = 0;
          ImageView imv;    private int TAKENPHOTO = 0;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from singleitemview.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.singleitemview);


    // Get position from intent passed from MainActivity.java
    Intent i = getIntent();
    //startActivityForResult(i, 1);

    int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

    // Open the Image adapter
    ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);


    // Locate the ImageView in singleitemview.xml
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

    // Get image and position from ImageAdapter.java and set into ImageView

    imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.mThumbIds[position]);
    //i = new Intent(SingleItemView.this, saveandshare.class);
//  startActivityForResult(i, 1);
    //Intent openNewActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), saveandshare.class);
//  startActivity(openNewActivity);



}




    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        imv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imv.setImageBitmap(bmp);




    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi please try below code , hope it will help you

write below code into your item click listener of gridView

```
Intent intent = new Intent(m_context, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("ImagePath", "Your Image path(either it is url or uri)");
startActivity(intent);
```

Write below code in your second activity

```
if(getIntent().getExtras() != null)
{
    String path;
    path = getIntent().getExtras().getString("ImagePath");
}
```

Write below code in your button click for pick image from gallery 
And use [Universalimageloader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) library for loading image

```
Intent m_galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(m_galleryIntent, 200);



  @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int p_requestCode, int p_resultCode, Intent p_data)
    {
        if(p_requestCode == 200 && p_resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            try
            {
                Uri m_selectedImageUri = p_data.getData();
                m_userSelectedImagePath = getPath(m_selectedImageUri);
                if(m_userSelectedImagePath.toString().startsWith("http"))
                {
                    m_loader.displayImage(m_userSelectedImagePath, m_ivScenarioImage);
                }
                else
                {
                    m_loader.displayImage("file://" + m_userSelectedImagePath, m_ivScenarioImage, m_options);
                }

            }
            catch(Exception m_e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

Use below function for store media

```
private File getOutputMediaFile()
    {

        File m_mediaFile;

            m_builder = new StringBuilder();
            m_builder.append(Constant.m_mediaDirectoryPath).append(Constant.IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);
            File m_imageStorageFile = new File(m_builder.toString());

            // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
            if(! m_imageStorageFile.exists())
            {
                if(! m_imageStorageFile.mkdirs())
                {
                    return null;
                }
            }
            // Create a media file name
            String m_timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat(Constant.TIME_STAMP_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault()).format(new java.util.Date());
            m_builder = new StringBuilder();
            m_builder.append(m_imageStorageFile.getPath()).append(File.separator).append("IMG_").append(m_timeStamp).append(".jpg");
            m_mediaFile = new File(m_builder.toString());


        return m_mediaFile;
    }
```

after above function you have to write below code in your save image button click

```
try
    {
       String saveImagePath;
        saveImagePath = getOutputMediaFile().getPath();
        m_bitmap = CommonUtills.getImageBitmap(m_context, m_userSelectedImagePath, 500, 500);
        ByteArrayOutputStream m_out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        if(m_bitmap != null)
        {
                 m_ivScenarioImage.setImageBitmap(m_bitmap);
        }
    }
    catch(Throwable m_e)
    {

    }


     public static Bitmap getImageBitmap(Context p_context,String p_filePath, int p_width, int p_height)
    {
        try
        {
            ExifInterface m_exif = new ExifInterface(p_filePath);
            int m_rotation = m_exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

            Matrix m_localMatrix = new Matrix();

            if(m_rotation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90)
                m_localMatrix.postRotate(90);
            else if(m_rotation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180)
                m_localMatrix.postRotate(180);
            else if(m_rotation == ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270)
                m_localMatrix.postRotate(270);
            else
                m_localMatrix.postRotate(0);

         //   Bitmap  m_retBmp = decodeFile(p_context, p_filePath,p_width,p_height);
           // Bitmap m_retBmp = ImageHelper.scaleImage(p_filePath, p_width, p_height);
          //  Bitmap m_retBmp =  CommonUtills.decodeFile(p_context, p_filePath, p_width, p_height);
            Bitmap m_retBmp =  CommonUtills.scaleImage(p_context,p_filePath,p_width,p_height);

            return Bitmap.createBitmap(m_retBmp, 0, 0, m_retBmp.getWidth(), m_retBmp.getHeight(), m_localMatrix, true);
        }
        catch(Throwable p_e)
        {

        }
        return null;
    }



     public static Bitmap scaleImage(Context p_context, String p_path, int p_reqHeight, int p_reqWidth)
    {
        Bitmap m_retBmp = null;
        try
        {
            System.gc();
            File m_file = new File(p_path);

            if (m_file.exists())
            {
                BitmapFactory.Options m_o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                m_o2.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeFile(m_file.getPath(), m_o2);

                m_o2.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(m_o2, p_reqHeight, p_reqWidth);

                m_o2.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                m_retBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(m_file.getPath(), m_o2);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception p_e)
        {

        }

        return m_retBmp;
    }


     private static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options p_options, int p_reqWidth, int p_reqHeight)
    {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int m_height = p_options.outHeight;
        final int m_width = p_options.outWidth;
        int m_inSampleSize = 1;

        if (m_height > p_reqHeight || m_width > p_reqWidth)
        {

            final int m_halfHeight = m_height / 2;
            final int m_halfWidth = m_width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((m_halfHeight / m_inSampleSize) > p_reqHeight && (m_halfWidth / m_inSampleSize) > p_reqWidth)
            {
                m_inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }
        return m_inSampleSize;
    }
```

Comment: Still seeing the capture image not the selected image from galley.I want to see both the images.

Comment: i have sent you code for store capture image also . Use getOutputMediaFile function . its working fine